# Catching exceptions from static methods - best practice in Java

Tags: java, static, try-catch

I need some advice please.

Since the static HelloWorld.Answer method throws a HelloException this code below gets an error.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HelloResult Hello(@RequestBody HelloRequest request) {

        HelloResult result = HelloWorld.Answer(request.getName());
            
        return result;        
    }
}
```

If I follow the Quick Fix ... from VS Code and add Try-Catch-block the result will be

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HelloResult Hello(@RequestBody HelloRequest request) {

        HelloResult result;

        try {
            result = HelloWorld.Answer(request.getName());
        } catch (HelloException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        return result;        
    }
}
```

which generates another error,

```
The local variable result may not have been initialized
```

so my question is - what is best practice in Java, what should be done in HelloController.Hello?

Comment: Since **HelloWorld.Answer** is throwing exception then the calling point must be wrapped in try/catch block. When you apply quick fix the VC just tries to handle it in it's own way and keeps the variable out of try/catch block. just put your variable in try block.

Comment: Yes of course :) , you're right - I was fooled by VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are not sure how to handle an exception, the correct action is not to catch it at all.

Instead, add it to the `throws` clause of the method where the code resides:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public HelloResult Hello(@RequestBody HelloRequest request)
throws HelloException {

    HelloResult result = HelloWorld.Answer(request.getName());
        
    return result;        
}
```

This is important because if the REST service cannot complete its operation properly, you want it to visibly fail.  You do not want the service to pretend that it worked when it did not in fact work.  (Think of any device or program which has done that.  If you press an elevator button and it doesn’t actually register, that’s pretty frustrating, isn’t it?)